# Is There Any Way To Customize The Menu/status/tab Bar Colors in Access 2016?

Tags: ms-access, ms-office, ms-access-2016, office-2016

Access 2016 allows a Colorful or White Office Theme plus one or two more when logged in to Microsoft. We have an Access 2007 Runtime application that we would like to upgrade to Runtime 2016 but the mismatch between 2016 colors and our 2007 form colors is terrible. The gray status bar and gray ribbon background of the Colorful theme is marginally acceptable but the red clay color of the menu bar background and tab text foreground is not. Is there any way possible to customize those colors to be blue? Thanks.

Edit: Adding screenshots to demonstrate precisely what customizing the menu and tab bar question is referring to.

We create our own menus. In Access 2007, the menus like Home, Create, and the ones we create, etc. have blue backgrounds with dark blue text. The tabs for Table 1, Table 2 have the same colors. All of our forms and marketing materials match this color scheme.

[image: Access 2007 screenshot]
In Access 2016 the menus have red clay background with grey foreground or grey background with red clay foreground. The tabs for Table 1, Table 2 have the same colors. This is what we need to change. Also noted is that Access 2007 title bar followed the Windows scheme but Access 2016 does not. Customizing 2016 properly would include this area somehow too.

[image: Access 2016 Colorful]
If I change the color scheme to White, the red clay color is still the dominant color.

[image: Access 2016 White]
If we cannot change these colors, we would have to redesign all of our forms and recreate all of our marketing materials. We would probably rewrite the application in another framework before redesigning everything in Access 2016.

P.S. What is Microsoft's official name for the color that looks like red clay to me? Thanks.

Comment: Do you have the accdb source file? I'm afraid accdr won't allow you to modify forms.

Comment: It's a reasonable question. Unfortunately I have no answer. I suspect these are baked into the apps. The colourful scheme is reddy-brown in Access because that's Access' characteristic colour (Word is dark blue, Excel is green, Outlook is a slightly lighter blue than Word, Powerpoint is an orangy-brown, etc). Perhaps the White theme is better for you?

Comment: krish KM - yes, we have a rather large application developed in Access.

Comment: andrew - I suspect they are baked into the apps too but we're leaving no stone unturned.  White has more grey and less red clay but is still an unacceptable discordance with the 2007 theme colors in our forms.  Even there, I presume Colorful is default and probably not something we can change programmatically, but that's a moot point.